# How do you make the background color of text higher than the text is?

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple menu and I have a problem.

In my menu, there are several different options with a `lightgrey` top border. When you hover over the links i have there backgrounds turn `lightgrey` as well but there is still a small line above each link where they `lightgrey` background color does not cover.

See the picture below:
[image]

I do not want that line to be there. I have tried using padding but to no effect.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  border-top: lightgrey 3px solid;
}
li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background: lightgrey;
}
ul {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Forum</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding margin-top: -1px; to your li a. Also, your code isn't complete for what you are showing in your example pic. Here is what it outputs http://jsfiddle.net/VWrCJ/ -- I added the green background.

Comment: please give in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sorry @AJ, My internet (Dial-up :-( ) Is to slow for JSFiddle. I would really like to use it though.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've included all of your CSS code for the nav list.

Comment: okay but you have not given in the full css .. i added it myself to the fiddle .. http://jsfiddle.net/yJ7y7/

Comment: Sorry about that! I accidentally left out a little bit. I have added it above. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Simple solution, `ul{padding:0; margin:0;} il{float:left; list-style:none;}`

Comment: Instead of a combination of display:block and float:right you could have tried display:inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided just to float the `<li>`'s, instead of using `inline-block` or using a table layout:

```
li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}
```

[Updated JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dyLbdwe/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="wrapper">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapper{
width: auto;
margin-right:25%;
margin-left:25%;
}
nav{
    display: table;
    background-color:darkgreen;
    border-top:lightgrey 3px solid; 
}
ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    padding: 10px;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size:20px;
    background:lightgrey;
}
```